# ExecError: error invoking 'nvcc --version': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvcc': 'nvcc'

Tags: pycuda

I am trying this code on my spyder(python3).

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import numpy

from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
mod = SourceModule("""
__global__ void multiply_them(float *dest, float *a, float *b)
{
  const int i = threadIdx.x;
  dest[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}
""")

multiply_them = mod.get_function("multiply_them")

a = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)
b = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)

dest = numpy.zeros_like(a)
multiply_them(
        drv.Out(dest), drv.In(a), drv.In(b),
        block=(400,1,1), grid=(1,1))

print (dest-a*b)
```

But couldn't run the code.

> ExecError: error invoking 'nvcc --version': [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory: 'nvcc': 'nvcc'

My nvcc -- version is

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

which nvcc
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc
  which spyder
  /home/anaconda3/bin/spyder
 $ which conda
/home/anaconda3/bin/conda

Device query :

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce 940MX"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          9.0 / 8.0
```

echo $PATH

```
/home/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/home/bin:/home/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

I have tried running the code on terminal. Then its running , but from the sourceModule line itself it shows errors.

```
"/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycuda-2017.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/compiler.py", line 255, in compile
    return compile_plain(source, options, keep, nvcc, cache_dir, target)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycuda-2017.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/compiler.py", line 137, in compile_plain
    stderr=stderr.decode("utf-8", "replace"))
pycuda.driver.CompileError: nvcc compilation of /tmp/tmpbdkxu33o/kernel.cu failed
[command: nvcc --cubin -arch sm_50 -I/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycuda-2017.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/cuda kernel.cu]
[stderr:
In file included from /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/..//include/cuda_runtime.h:78:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/..//include/host_config.h:119:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
  ^~~~~
]
```

Also i have tried on my Jupiter notebook and on other Cuda installed system. But couldn't identify the problem. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Probably a matter of [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) setting (used internally by [exec](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) functions) but you don't give enough details. Your `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc` is unusual. You should fix, or at least explicitly tell, what is your `$PATH`

Comment: Don't comment your question, but do edit it. You can query your `PATH` with  `echo $PATH` in the terminal. And the last message is quite understandable. You need an old `gcc`, version 5.0 (which is obsolete). Perhaps you should update your CUDA or ask that question on some CUDA specific forum

Comment: That should go into your question (which is so unclear that I voted to close it, because you have not edited it), and that does not give your `PATH`

Comment: BTW, your `PATH` is a big mess that you should try to clean. Probably by doing that you'll solve your problem

Comment: Spend an hour on reading about `PATH`. Think. Clean the mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working on python2 virtual environment through terminal.