# pytools.prefork.ExecError: error invoking 'nvcc --version': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: gpu, ubuntu-16.04, nvidia, pycuda

I have install `pycuda` and I am trying to test it with code below.

```py
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy
a = numpy.random.randn(4,4)
a = a.astype(numpy.float32)
a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(a_gpu, a)

mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void doublify(float *a)
  {
    int idx = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y*4;
    a[idx] *= 2;
  }
  """)

func = mod.get_function("doublify")
func(a_gpu, block=(4,4,1))

a_doubled = numpy.empty_like(a)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(a_doubled, a_gpu)
print a_doubled
print a
```

I'm getting the following error:

> pytools.prefork.ExecError: error invoking 'nvcc --version': [Errno 2]
>   No such file or directory

Comment: i have taken this sample program from [link](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/tutorial.html)

Comment: Regarding answer in [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50902898/execerror-error-invoking-nvcc-version-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory  I am already using python 2.7 and trying to test it from terminal still I am facing this issue

Answer (score 2):

It's working after adding the below lines in the .bashrc file

export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}$ 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}

Steps

1. find .bashrc file.
2. Add above lines to it.
3. source .bashrc
4. To Test run command "nvcc --version"

link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/885610/nvcc-version-command-says-nvcc-is-not-installed   helped

Answer (score 2):

In case this error reported, open the *compiler.py* file and in the `compile_plain()` function add the following line:

```py
nvcc = '/usr/local/cuda/bin/' + nvcc
```

the *compiler.py* file is located in:
"/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pycuda-2020.1-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/compiler.py"

So the final code will be something like this:

```py
    def compile_plain(source, options, keep, nvcc, cache_dir, target="cubin"):
        from os.path import join
    
        assert target in ["cubin", "ptx", "fatbin"]
        nvcc = '/usr/local/cuda/bin/' + nvcc # --> here is the new line
        
        if cache_dir:
            checksum = _new_md5()
            ...
```

Save it and that's all